# OpenGL ES - How to implement the Glossy Shader in Blender Cycles Render?

Tags: android, opengl-es, blender

In [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) Cycles render, there's a shader type called [Glossy](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Glossy). Now I want to implement this glossy shader using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android. I'm wondering where can I find a GLSL implementation of this shader? Below is an image displaying the glossy reflection (see the reflection on the plane).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That effect is basically just a gaussian blur filter.  There is a good example of this for OpenGL ES 2.0 in the [PowerVR SDK](http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/) in these files:

\Examples\Intermediate\Bloom\OGLES2\BlurVertShader.vsh:

```
// Blur filter kernel shader
//
// 0  1  2  3  4
// x--x--X--x--x    <- original filter kernel
//   y---X---y      <- filter kernel abusing the hardware texture filtering
//       |
//      texel center
//
// 
// Using hardware texture filtering, the amount of samples can be
// reduced to three. To calculate the offset, use this formula:
// d = w1 / (w1 + w2),  whereas w1 and w2 denote the filter kernel weights

attribute highp   vec3  inVertex;
attribute mediump vec2  inTexCoord;

uniform mediump float  TexelOffsetX;
uniform mediump float  TexelOffsetY;

varying mediump vec2  TexCoord0;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord1;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord2;

void main()
{
    // Pass through vertex
    gl_Position = vec4(inVertex, 1.0);

    // Calculate texture offsets and pass through   
    mediump vec2 offset = vec2(TexelOffsetX, TexelOffsetY);

    TexCoord0 = inTexCoord - offset;
    TexCoord1 = inTexCoord;
    TexCoord2 = inTexCoord + offset;    

}
```

\Examples\Intermediate\Bloom\OGLES2\BlurFragShader.vsh:

```
uniform lowp sampler2D  sTexture;

/* 
  Separated Gaussian 5x5 filter, first row:         1  5  6  5  1
*/

varying mediump vec2  TexCoord0;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord1;
varying mediump vec2  TexCoord2;

void main()
{
    lowp vec3 color = texture2D(sTexture, TexCoord0).rgb * 0.333333;
    color = color + texture2D(sTexture, TexCoord1).rgb * 0.333333;
    color = color + texture2D(sTexture, TexCoord2).rgb * 0.333333;    

    gl_FragColor.rgb = color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @ClayMontgomery, the Gaussian blur filter did create some blur, but the blur is not enough. By adding texCoord3, texCoord4...(sample more neighboring pixels), the blur increases, but this takes more time of calculation. I think we need lots of sampling here in order to get the effects in above image, right? Is there any other efficient way?

Comment: Yes, a less expensive way would be to just increase the value of "offset".  Both might be required to get the result you want.  Blur filters are computationally expensive.  You could also run this through multi-passes by rendering to a texture attached FBO which could theoretically provide infinite blur with infinite passes.